# Maxwell relation on termodynamics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

I have to use Mawxell relations to reduce $\bigg(\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial P}\bigg)_f$ to a relation in function of $\alpha,c_p,\kappa_T$. I keep getting a relation in function of $P$, I am stuck.

Comment: Just a thought:  It might help if you defined the parameters you are using.

Comment: What is your starting point? What is $f$?